# android things and raspberry pi 3 camera quality/resolution

Tags: android, camera, raspberry-pi3, android-things

I recently started to use Android Things (0.5.1-devpreview
) on Raspberry Pi 3. 
I noticed that the camera quality and resolution are so bad and low.

To interact with the camera I'm using the DoorbellCamera class provided with the Doorbell example from Google.

Calling the dumpFormatInfo I get this results:

```
D/CameraHandler: Using camera id 0
D/CameraHandler: Getting sizes for format: 1
D/CameraHandler:    320x240
D/CameraHandler:    640x480
D/CameraHandler: Getting sizes for format: 20
D/CameraHandler:    320x240
D/CameraHandler:    640x480
D/CameraHandler: Getting sizes for format: 256
D/CameraHandler:    320x240
D/CameraHandler:    640x480
D/CameraHandler: Getting sizes for format: 34
D/CameraHandler:    320x240
D/CameraHandler:    640x480
D/CameraHandler: Getting sizes for format: 35
D/CameraHandler:    320x240
D/CameraHandler:    640x480
D/CameraHandler: Effect available: 0
```

The camera I'm using is Waveshare Raspberry Pi Camera 1080p and, using linux and raspistill command, I can correctly get full 1080p pictures/video.

Any idea how to make it happen also on Android Things?

thanks

Comment: I recommend you upvote and track the existing bug filed on this: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/37134104

Comment: will do it now. it's a shame, I'm trying to find any workaround, but nothing till now.